# C# check user input for specific file name and open file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file-exists

I have a project where I ask the user to verify if a file exists on their machine. They input the path and the code checks to see if the file exists.

I am wanting to see if the user inputs a specific txt file and if so open the file.

The file name I'm looking for is "SavingsAccount.txt".
The file could be in any directory.

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the file path location");
Console.WriteLine("e.g.C:\\Users\\acke9387\\Downloads\\file1.txt");

bool Exist = true;
while (Exist)
{
      String file = Console.ReadLine();
      bool DoesFileExist = System.IO.File.Exists(file);

      if (DoesFileExist == true)
      {
            Console.WriteLine("File does exist");

            if (file.Contains("SavingsAccount.txt"))
            {
                  System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file);
            }
      }
      if (DoesFileExist == false)
      {
            Console.WriteLine("File does not exist, Please enter a valid path.");
      }
}
```

Comment: what is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You just can do it simply in a line of code, no need to rewrite it yourself.

`string[] filePathList = new DirectoryInfo("FILE_PATH").GetFiles("FILE_NAME", SearchOption.AllDirectories);`

More information at [Microsoft Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_System_String_).